# Spring Data + MongoDb Query takes lot of time

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have Nav Collection which is having 178097 records.

below is sample collectin.

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5911cdbe891123031552713e"), 
"_class" : "org.maruti.mfm.data.entity.Nav", 
"asAtDate" : ISODate("2017-05-07T16:00:00.000+0000"), 
"nav" : 10.1102, 
"repurchasePrice" : 0.0, 
"salePrice" : 0.0, 
"latest" : false, 
"scheme" : DBRef("scheme", ObjectId("58d760a32ac5bf0405b69afa"))
}
```

from these 178097, only 14174 records has latest : true.

Below is my mapping in java

```
@Document
```

public class Nav extends BaseEntity {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private String id;

@Indexed
@DBRef
private Scheme scheme;

@Indexed
private Date asAtDate;
private double nav;
private double repurchasePrice;
private double salePrice;

@Indexed
private boolean latest;
```

However when i use below method to find all nav collection which is having latest flag true. it's taking more then 1 minute to just find around 14k records out of 178k records.

```
public interface NavRepository extends MongoRepository<Nav, String> {

    List<Nav> findByLatest(boolean latest);

}
```

Is there anyway to improve the performance.

Result of explain

```
db.nav.find({latest:true}).explain();
{
"queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "mfmunshi.nav",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "latest" : {
            "$eq" : true
        }
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH",
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            "keyPattern" : {
                "latest" : 1
            },
            "indexName" : "latest",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                "latest" : [ ]
            },
            "isUnique" : false,
            "isSparse" : false,
            "isPartial" : false,
            "indexVersion" : 2,
            "direction" : "forward",
            "indexBounds" : {
                "latest" : [
                    "[true, true]"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
},
 "serverInfo" : {
    "host" : "Jigars-MacBook-Pro.local",
    "port" : 27017,
    "version" : "3.4.2",
    "gitVersion" : "3f76e40c105fc223b3e5aac3e20dcd026b83b38b"
},
"ok" : 1
}
```

The query took 0.057 seconds when i fired it from terminal window.

Comment: Let's first locate problem - is it in DB or in SpringData. Check your collection - does index on `latest` really exist? Run query in mongo shell `db.nav.find({latest:true})` -  how many time it takes? If it's slow too, check explain() for query - does it uses index?

Comment: Updated the result of explain and query execution time from terminal window.

Comment: when you say terminal window, do you mean from mongo console or  from db browser like Mongochef or Robomongo. The reason I am asking is, these db browsers will not fetch all when you run the command, it fetches first 50 or 100 and then allow pagination. May be that is the reason its fast. For db  size with 178097 records i think the time 1 minute is normal I guess. You are not using any projection or pagination also, so it has to fetch all the fields of all the documents and return it.

Comment: I am using Studio 3T, it fetches all the records without pagination. within a second.

Comment: Query execution on MongoDB layer is fast, so the delay is lying in the SpringData layer, check on your Heap allocation for JVM and see if more allocation of memory to Heap shows any difference in the execution time